# What are the new enhancements in scrapy 0.24.0?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, scrapyd

What are the features added to , removed from scrapy 0.24.0?. How does it is differ from the earlier version ?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, the most important change for me was the namespace cleanup.
From 0.24 onwards you can do:

```
from scrapy import Spider, Request, Item, Field
```

Previously you had to remember the module for each one of these.

Also, the response object got a few goodies: now you can do `response.selector` to get a Selector for that response (no need to instantiate one anymore), and you also have new shortcut methods `response.css()` and `response.xpath()` too.

There are several other small changes and fixes, the complete release notes are available here: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/news.html#id5